# Eliminating Negative or Non_Negative values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, automation

-)I'm working on an automation task in python wherein in each row the 1st negative value should be added up with the 1st non-negative value from the left. Further, the result should replace the positive value and 0 should replace the negative value

-)This process should continue until the entire row contains all negative or all positive values.

```
**CUSTOMER    <30Days  31-60 Days  61-90Days  91-120Days  120-180Days 180-360Days  >360Days**
ABC             -2     23           2          3            2               2    -1
        
(>360Days)+(180-360Days)
     -1   +   2

CUSTOMER    <30Days  31-60 Days  61-90Days  91-120Days  120-180Days 180-360Days  >360Days
ABC             -2     23           2          3            2               1    0

(<30Days)+(180-360Days)
   -2    +  1



 CUSTOMER    <30Days  31-60 Days  61-90Days  91-120Days  120-180Days 180-360Days  >360Days
  ABC             0     23           2          3            2               -1    0

(180-360Days)+(120-180Days)
     -1      +    2

CUSTOMER    <30Days  31-60 Days  61-90Days  91-120Days  120-180Days 180-360Days  >360Days
  ABC             0     23           2          3            2               0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Empty DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame()

#Enter the data
new_row={'CUSTOMER':'ABC','<30Days':-2,'31-60 Days':23,'61-90Days':2,'91-120Days':3,'120-180Days':2,'180-360Days':2,'>360Days':-1}
df=df.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)

#Keep columns order as per the requirement
df=df[['CUSTOMER','<30Days','31-60 Days','61-90Days','91-120Days','120-180Days','180-360Days','>360Days']]

#Take column names and reverse the order
ls=list(df.columns)
ls.reverse()

#Remove non integer column
ls.remove('CUSTOMER')

#Initialize variables
flag1=1
flag=0
new_ls=[]
new_ls_index=[]


for j in range(len(df)):
    while flag1!=0:
        #Perform logic
        for i in ls:    
            if int(df[i][j]) < 0 and flag == 0:
               new_ls.append(int(df[i][j]))
               new_ls_index.append(i)
               flag=1
            elif flag==1 and int(df[i][j]) >= 0 :
               new_ls.append(int(df[i][j]))
               new_ls_index.append(i)
               flag=2
            elif flag==2:
               df[new_ls_index[1]]=new_ls[0]+new_ls[1]
               df[new_ls_index[0]]=0
               flag=0
               new_ls=[]
               new_ls_index=[]
        
        #Check all values in row either positive or negative
        if new_ls==[]:
            new_ls_neg=[]
            new_ls_pos=[]
            for i in ls: 
                if int(df[i][j]) < 0:
                   new_ls_neg.append(int(df[i][j]))
                if int(df[i][j]) >= 0 :                   
                   new_ls_pos.append(int(df[i][j]))
                   
            if len(new_ls_neg)==len(ls) or len(new_ls_pos)==len(ls):
               flag1=0 #Set flag to stop the loop
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help..The code works fine now but when i provide an input file it is not yielding the correct Result .

Comment: Can you please replicate the same code with an input excel file having the same columns.                         df=pd.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename()

Comment: If you have successfully read the file into df then you have to use this code from "#Keep columns order as per the requirement" line in order to work with input file